# Is there a way to set an image on a jbutton without setting it in the constructor?

Tags: java, jbutton, imageicon

I want to set an `ImageIcon` on a `JButton` but I don't want to set it via this way:

```
JButton btnTest = new JButton(new ImageIcon("IMAGE PATH"));
```

Is there a way I could do something like below, rather then setting it in the constructor?

```
btnTest.setImageIcon();
btnTest.setText(new ImageIcon().something....)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Use `JButton.setIcon(Icon)`.**

```
btnTest.setIcon(new ImageIcon("IMAGE PATH"));
```

There are also extra methods to set custom icons when the button is rolled over, pressed, selected, disabled, or different combinations of those states.

The [Java API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/) is a great source for this type of information.  Bookmark it and refer to it often!

Comment: Thanks! I had a custom class extending jbutton, that I couldn't pass arguments through the constructor. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("path_to_icon");
btnTest.setIcon(icon);
```